# mysql select data with calculation between 2 tables and group by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql tables like bellow:

```
Table income                           Table expense
id  amount         date                id  amount         date
1   200         2011-12-10             1   100         2011-12-21
2   300         2011-12-14             2   150         2012-01-01
3   500         2012-01-05             2   200         2012-01-03
```

I want to get data in this way:

```
month              profit
december, 2011     400
january, 2012      150
```

Is this possible in a single query?

Comment: I think your math is wrong, January 2012 has 350 in expenses, and only 500 income, so your profit should be **150**? or am I missing something? Also can you define the table relationship? I see dupe id's in `expense`

Comment: don't worry about the calculation. I have given an example here

Comment: umm, I only ask because your example is invalid, and you want an **answer** from us that is valid? Or should we make up something you don't care about and just "not worry about it"

Comment: If you can please give me a valid answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a union with some date magic for the aggregate:

```
select
    date_format(x.date, '%M %Y') as `month`,
    sum(amount) as profit
from
    (select amount, date
     from income
     union all
     select amount*-1 as amount, date
     from expense
    ) x
group by
    date_format(x.date, '%M %Y')
```

The specific thing we're using here is [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get the dates the way we want it. Also, we're multiplying `amount` by `-1` when it comes from `expense` to make the calculation correct. Of course, we could have returned different columns for `income` and `expense` and then did the math on them in the sum, such as `sum(x.income_amount, x.expense_amount)`, but there's no need to do that when you can just quickly do a `*-1` to the column on before it hits the `sum`.

The other important thing is the `group by`. Here, we're grouping by a function that formats the date as `Month, YYYY`, so it will get the divisions you're looking for.

Comment: this is great! you just saved a lot of time of mine. Thanks a lot.